# How to built a Android Single App Mode

Tags: android, kiosk

I want to use a Android Phone as a controlling unit for one of my projects.
In this the Smartphone is fixed on the hardware.
Tasks for the smartphone are:

- Communication via Bluetooth
- Handling User Input (e.g. PIN-Entry)
- Turning on/off vibration, led ,...

So I wrote a App which does all the things I want.

Now I want that the Smartphone can only be used for this application. 
Maybe you can give me some Ideas how to manage this.
I heard about 'kiosk-mode', could this be a solution.
Another option would be a custom ROM or is it possible to get a 'basic-android' without a launcher an just one single app.
I just want some ideas and usefull suggestions from you:)

Comment: There are several ways to lock down your device to a single app. I outlined some of them with pros/cons in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644803/2888763

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android version "L" there is a way to do that. It is called Task Locking, however it needs root access.
There is a lot of tutorials on this site. I just don't want to copy-paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/

Pretty good article about task locking and device ownership. And unlike Evgeniy said, root is not needed.